# Loopback: Use multiple include filters in query

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to include multiple related models in a query:

```
/distributors?filter[include][depots]=drivers&filter[include]=delivery_times
```

However this seems to duplicate the drivers for each distributor and doesn't return any delivery_time.

This

```
/distributors?filter[include]=delivery_times
```

and this:

```
/distributors?filter[include][depots]=drivers
```

seems to work fine though.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple include should be done like this on REST:

```
/distributors?filter[include][0][depots]=drivers&filter[include][1]=delivery_times
```

Comment: great! I couldn't find this in the documentation. do you have any reference by any chance?

Comment: No sorry, this is what I used since Loopbackjs v2 - but I couldn't manage to find a doc example like this anymore...